# Retrieve wall photo from status through graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

How can I retrieve [this photo](https://www.facebook.com/412778502140672/posts/425592530859269) through graph API?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get photos posted to the wall of an event like your sample.

I had a client last summer who started a contest that had people post photos to an event wall. They asked me to get them for display on their website. We had to manually download them to get them.

You can look at the `feed` for that event using

```
/412778502140672/event?fields=feed
```

But there are no attachments, and no connections. I don't believe it is possible to even get an event's `stream` using FQL.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `/412778502140672/feed`? And yes, there are no photos or attachments.

Comment: No. It's not the same. If it's part of the page's feed you can get the attachments. You can't on an event feed.

Comment: 412778502140672 is event, not page? So [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=412778502140672%2Fevent%3Ffields%3Dfeed) vs. [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=412778502140672%2Ffeed). This is not the same (for things in the feed)?

Comment: 412778502140672 is a page, but the photo you referenced in your original post is posted on the wall of one of that page's events. Events have a separate feed from the main page, and the event feed does not have the same features as a regular feed.

Comment: 412778502140672 is event. And I am saying that `/412778502140672/event?fields=feed` is the same as `/412778502140672/feed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Android then this way can help you

```
            Request r=Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {


            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JSONObject jso=null;
                try{
    //Parse json here

                }
                catch ( Exception e)
                {
                    //Log.d(sTag,e.getMessage());
                }



            }




        });
        Bundle paramsPics=r.getParameters();
        paramsPics.putString("fields", 
                "photos");




        r.setParameters(paramsPics);
        Response response=r.executeAndWait();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the "me/home" API call, an item that has a photo will have a "picture" field with the source URL for a low resolution picture. To get to original high resolution picture, and dimensional variants of it, you have to do another API call using the "object_id" field in the same JSONObject as the "picture" field.

Doing the graph call for the "object_id" will then give you a "source" field with the original source image URL, as well as an array of different image sizes.

EDIT:

Set the graph path to "412778502140672_425592530859269" for the post.

Set the graph path to "482760011786004" for the photo.

Comment: Please tell me the exact URL of the query to extract the photo from the post I gave in the question. (I do not believe what you are writing here is the answer.)

Comment: How do I get from "412778502140672_425592530859269" to "482760011786004"?

Comment: I got "482760011786004" from clicking on the picture in that post and looking at the URL. It doesn't show up anywhere in the response for "412778502140672_425592530859269". So if all you need is the photo, then the second graph path is all you need.

Comment: I need to programatically get photo from the post. How does looking the photo ID manually help me in this? This is just an example. So for such types of posts, how do I get any information about photo in general?

Comment: That's what the original answer is. There's an "object_id" field in the graph result for a post. If you do a graph request for that number you get from "object_id", you'll get the detailed photo info. For some reason, the example you gave me doesn't have it though, so I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Exactly this is why I am asking. I know that for some other posts it works. But in this case it does not. This is the question. How to make it work in this case(s).